# After upgrade to xcode 8.3 Apple ResearhKit pop up with error "Redefinition of module 'Research Kit'

Tags: ios, xcode8, researchkit

After upgrade to xcode 8.3 and try to re-compile my ios app. The Apple ResearchKit module.modulemap pop up with error. The error message is "Lexical or Preprocessor issue" and "Redefinition of module 'ResearchKit'. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue.  I ended up having to delete the ResearchKit my project was using, and re-embed a fresh download.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it and let you know.